# SharePoint Foundation 2013 dash after page title

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, administration

I have a SP 2013 Foundation team site I named Home when I created it.   In Title and Description, I have Home entered there.  The page title on top of my browser says "Home - Home".  I clear out Home in Title and Description and now the page title says " - Home".

I can't edit the page title in the page properties like with a publishing page.  Can I get rid of that second "Home"?  Can this be controlled in a central place?

[image]